# Onchange function not working after initialisation of daterangepicker

Tags: javascript

Once i used setrange for predefined date into datepicker. My onchange function is not working anymore.

I have added the code. Please check and advise
Thanks in advance

```js
$("#daterangeperiod").daterangepicker();
$("#daterangeperiod").daterangepicker("setRange", {
                                      start: new Date(event.item.dataContext.year, monthnum, 1),
                                      end:   new Date(event.item.dataContext.year, monthnum + 1, 0)
                                      
==========================================================
$('#daterangeperiod').change(function(){ 

                $.ajax({                             
                        url: someurl,
                        type: "get",
                        success: function(data){
                          
                            $('selector').html(data);
                    }
                });

            });
```

```html
<input type="text" id="daterangeperiod" name="daterangeperiod" />
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please step first to [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've applied your daterangepicker to your element, you can't treat it like a regular text input box anymore, since the daterangepicker code has transformed that into more complex html.

It's hard to tell which daterangepicker you're using (there are several around), but it should have its own events, and its documentation should tell you how to use them. For example, the one from [daterangepicker.com](http://www.daterangepicker.com/) has events like `apply.daterangepicker` that might be useful.

Comment: I got the solution. I have used change event into the daterangepicker change: function (event, data) { event.preventDefault(); changeEventTrack(); },  });
Inside change function, i called my custom function and that solved my problem.

Comment: That comes down to what I've said: you're now using the change function of your daterangepicker control. So maybe you can accept my answer. :-)